# Building a preference screen with Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

i have to build a new Android app. Since Jetpack Compose is now stable i want to build the entire UI with that. Further i need also a Preference/Settings screen where the user can specify his preferences. According the doc it is still recommended doing this via Fragments.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings

I found also an external library witch would provide this functionality in the compose way.
https://github.com/alorma/Compose-Settings

Has anybody done this before? Whats the "cleanest" way for doing that?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have implemented an app in compose and I created the settings screen using the tools available in Jetpack Compose, without fragments.

The way I did this is create a composable for each settings option, that contains a title, and optional subtitle, and a checkbox, which indicates if the option is enabled or not.

These options are then added to a column (or a grid, if you have a tablet, it's easy to support both in compose); you just have to hook the clicks on the checkbox to your viewmodel to change the setting and then refresh the UI.

If you have other kinds of settings entries you can define your own composables for those as well. In my case I have other settings options that open a dialog where the user can configure some parameters, I have another composable function for this kind of settings row as well.

This is personal opinion, but I prefer to stay away from 3rd party libraries unless a) they provide significant value and b) they're from a source that offers some kind of maintenance and bug fixes guarantees. I don't know about that library you mentioned, but if you include 3rd party libraries, you need to be aware you are relinquishing control over parts of your app so you need to balance the cost/benefit ratio.

Comment: I have the same opinion regarding 3rd party libraries. So for managing states, i.e. after an app restart you use rememberSavable?
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#restore-ui-state

Comment: Yes, if you want to persist something across recreating, you can use rememberSaveable, or store it in a viewmodel (the latter would be preferable).

Comment: now, how to store these settings in the Android Setting page??

Answer (score 3):

I've created a library implementing Preference for Jetpack Compose Material 3, designed with both extensibility and ease-of-use in mind:

https://github.com/zhanghai/ComposePreference

[image: Screenshot]

You may either use it as simple as:

```
ProvidePreferenceLocals {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        switchPreference(
            key = "switch_preference",
            defaultValue = false,
            title = { Text(text = "Switch preference") },
            icon = { Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Info, contentDescription = null) },
            summary = { Text(text = if (it) "On" else "Off") }
        )
    }
}
```

Or explore other more extensible forms of APIs in this library.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing. I found the use of a Repository in the [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-preferences-datastore#0) a little confusing. I wanted a simple way to define keys and default values once.

My approach is to have an interface and provide a `DataStore` using `CompositionLocalProvider` (inspired by React.js, not sure if it's considered best practice).

```
/**
 * Convenient methods to get data from a DataStore
 */
interface Preference<V> {
    /**
     * Key to get a preference
     */
    val key: Preferences.Key<V>
    /**
     * A context is necessary to have a default value that matches with the current theme or language
     */
    val defaultValueFromContext: Context.() -> V

    // value
    fun value(preferences: Preferences): V? = preferences[key]
    fun valueOrDefault(preferences: Preferences, context: Context): V =
        value(preferences) ?: defaultValueFromContext(context)

    // read
    fun flow(dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>): Flow<V?> =
        dataStore.data.map { value(it) }.distinctUntilChanged()
    fun flowOrDefault(dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>, context: Context): Flow<V> =
        dataStore.data.map { valueOrDefault(it, context) }.distinctUntilChanged()

    // write
    suspend fun edit(dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>, newValue: (currentValue: V?) -> V) {
        dataStore.edit {
            it[key] = newValue(value(it))
        }
    }
}
```

```
/**
 * CompositionLocal providing a datastore
 */
val LocalDataStore = compositionLocalOf { dummyDataStore } // TODO use static?

@Composable
fun DataStoreProvider(
    dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> = LocalContext.current.settingsDataStore,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) =
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalDataStore.provides(dataStore)) { content() }
```

I didn't use a ViewModel because I don't think it's considered best practice to have multiple view models per screen (for each preference), and I didn't find a way to have a single ViewModel for a variable number of preferences. So, I just use extension functions.

```
/**
 * Avoid having to specify an initial value
 */
@Composable
fun <V> Preference<V>.stateOrDefault() =
    flowOrDefault(LocalDataStore.current, LocalContext.current).collectAsState(initial = defaultValue()) // TODO with lifecycle

@Composable
fun <V> Preference<V>.defaultValue() = defaultValueFromContext(LocalContext.current)
```

After laying the groundwork, doing something like changing the theme is relatively easy.

```
AppTheme(darkTheme = DARK_THEME.stateOrDefault().value) { }
```

```
class DarkThemePreference(keyName: String = "dark_theme") : BooleanPreference(keyName) {
    override val defaultValueFromContext: Context.() -> Boolean
        get() = {
            isSystemInDarkTheme(resources.configuration)
        }
}

fun isSystemInDarkTheme(configuration: Configuration): Boolean {
    return (configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
}
```

```
@Composable
fun SwitchPreference(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    title: String,
    preference: Preference<Boolean>,
    description: String? = null,
    icon: ComposeFunction? = null
) {
    var checked by preference.optimisticState()

    PreferenceItem(
        modifier = modifier,
        title = title,
        description = description,
        icon = icon,
        onClick = { checked = !checked },
        action = {
            Switch(checked = checked, onCheckedChange = { checked = it })
        })
}
```

For the theming, I also use a `CompositionLocal`.

```
// make sure values are divisible by 4 for consistency
val Int.unit: Dp
    get() = this * 4.dp

val Int.bigUnit: Dp
    get() = 4.unit

/**
 * Values for placing and spacing elements
 */
data class Spacing(
    val itemMinHeight: Dp = 3.bigUnit,
    val itemPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(horizontal = 1.bigUnit, vertical = 2.unit),
    val iconPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(end = 5.unit),
    val actionPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(start = 1.unit),
    val dividerPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(bottom = 4.bigUnit)
)

val LocalSpacing = compositionLocalOf { Spacing() }
```

[Source code](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/compose-preferences)